# Hodges-Lehmann estimator as a percentage?

Tags: group-differences, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I'm comparing samples X and Y (of sizes M and N respectively). I need to report whether the samples are statistically different (Mann-Whitney U-test) and by how much (Hodges-Lehmann estimator) to people who are not too familiar with statistics.

For reporting the difference between two groups, would it be OK to calculate relative pairwise differences w.r.t. their arithmetic mean, i.e.:

$d_{ij} = \frac{(y_j - x_i)}{\frac{(y_j + x_i)}2}$

and then report the median of the rel. differences as a percentage difference in location?

EDIT:

All data is > 0.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "OK" and on the nature of the data.  For instance, what would you do if any $y_j+x_i$ were zero?

Comment: If you want to report some effect-size like measure as a proportion, the most obvious thing to report would be the proportion of times that an X-observation exceeded a Y-observation (or vice-versa). You'd use Hodges-Lehmann if you wanted to measure the difference in location in the units of the original data.

Comment: @Glen_b Can effect size based on a z-score for Mann-Whitney be interpreted as a relative difference between the two samples?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "a relative difference between two samples". Difference in what sense? (It's not a measure of a standardized location shift for example) Relative to what? If you can make that more precise it might be reasonable to ask it as a new question.